# Plasma ethereum

Tags: ether, plasma

I am reading the plasma white paper and I don't understand the following part :
[image: Plasma WhitePaper]

The problematic sentence is :
"Additionally, signiﬁcant scalability is achieved by minimizing the funds represented in a spend from a contract to a single bit in a bitmap"

how you can represent the funds in a single bit ?

It is difficult for me to imagine a spend of 5000 PETH represented with 1 bit

Thanks